# One empty error Eclipse/Kepler in Problems view

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, eclipse-kepler

An empty error still present in Eclipse **Problems** view.

[image: Eclipse empty error]

I use Eclipse KEPLER SR2.
The project is a Maven War project and is working fine.

If I select error, I can delete it, but after a new **Project > Clean...** she returns...

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried `ALT+F5` on the project?

Comment: Have you tried to look at the resource specified in the entry 'tfmWeb' ? Ctrl + Shft + r will allow you to search for the resource...not sure what it is though.